# Symfony returns "internal server error 500" for api

Tags: javascript, php, vue.js, symfony

I am working with Vuejs and symfony (for api), I am new in Symfony and i am working in existing project (created by someone) so i am
trying to run project on local server but my "Api's" not working so right now data is not fetching/showing in homepage,I am not sure but maybe some
wrong with ".env" file Here is current code of my .env file,what changes should be done for fix this problem ?

```
# DATABASE_URL="sqlite:///%kernel.project_dir%/var/data.db"
# DATABASE_URL="mysql://root:@127.0.0.1:3306/dating_xxxxxxx?serverVersion=5.7&charset=utf8mb4"
DATABASE_URL="mysql://localhost/phpmyadmin/index.php?route=/database/structure&db=dating_sugar_sta"
##DATABASE_URL="postgresql://symfony:ChangeMe@127.0.0.1:xxxx/app?serverVersion=13&charset=utf8"
###< doctrine/doctrine-bundle ###
```

My current working url in localhost is

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/
```

Comment: check the server (symphony?) log to determine what is causing the error

Comment: Your DB string connection is strange, I think it's wrong ! You have a sample of the right way, you have to find your db credentials and find the correct string connection.